# How to use MVC3 data annotations for files?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am working on a programming project where I need to upload files, but I don't know how I would correctly use data annotations to do this, could anyone give me a hand?

I am using the Code First Entity framework and the value I want to store in the database is simply the url to the image on the server. I so far only have this snippet of code for that.

```
[DisplayName("Ad Image")]
[StringLength(1024)]
public string   AdImageUrl  { get; set; }
```

I am trying to get data validation working so I can use the same data validation systems as used for other input fields for checking if the correct filetype is send.

Comment: Your question is vast and vague, can expand?

Comment: I added a little extra information

Comment: In response to "checking if the correct file type is sent", you can use the FileExtensionAttribute. See the docs here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.fileextensionsattribute.aspx

Comment: Actually you have to check only string, if input=file is not without value, after that you just use HttpPostedFile to save the data from.